# Convert fasta to ascii?

Tags: gene, sequence-analysis, gene-therapy

Is there an algorithm or tool to convert a fasta sequence file (such as the file linked below) into an ascii file for the purpose of gene synthesis?

https://www.rcsb.org/fasta/entry/6EQJ

To the best of my knowledge, the fasta file contains the entire sequence of a protein, in which case there must be a way to convert it to a standard ascii formatted sequence, but I havent been able to find any tools to do so.

Comment: Why would gene synthesis require ascii format?

Comment: What do you mean with ascii? FASTA **is** plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FASTA files are just text files, so you can open them up in your favorite text editor to see what they look like. The file you linked has a single entry. The first line begins with `>` and contains information about the sequence, delimited by `|` characters – the accession number, chain info, gene name, species, etc. Subsequent lines are just the protein sequence using the standard 20-letter alphabet for amino acids, or the nucleotide sequence from 5'-3' using ACTG. There can be multiple entries in a file, delineated by one or more blank lines.

If for whatever reason your instrument or vendor won't accept FASTA files, a very simple low-throughput solution is to just delete the first line of single-entry files, or delete any lines beginning with `>` for multiple-entry files. If you have many files to process, this can be automated using Unix/Linux command line tools or a scripting language like Python or Perl.